# Not using the returned values sometimes returns both true and false in similar conditions

Tags: c, function, return, boolean, c89

According to C89 standard the following code is legit:

```
A_Function_that_returns_true();
```

But the following is false
(Since the returned value is not used-This can be solved simply by declaring a bool variable)

```
(5>3) && (7>6);
```

But what’s the difference between both examples? In both I didn’t use the returned value so why one is true and one is false that doesn’t sound right

Comment: I do not think that the second line is syntactically incorrect, it is a valid statement without any effect.

Comment: The second example ***definitiely*** has no effect; the first case, even though you don't use the returned value of the function, ***may*** have an effect, but we don't know (and neither does the compiler) what the internals of the function are.

Comment: Both code snippets are "legit". `why one is true and one is false` - are you specifying the return value of the expressions, or... How are you measuring if one example is "false" or "true" and what do you mean by that? Is `1==1 && 2==2;` having the state "false" or "true"?

Comment: @KamilCuk `1==1 && 2==2` evaluates to `true`, I don't see how this could be disputed

Comment: What "returned value" exactly are you talking about in example 2? There is no function call that could return anything. This is just an expression which is evaluated. And the value it is evaluated to is `true`

Comment: Can you clarify the question, based on the comments?

Comment: "declaring a bool variable" will only change the warning from "statement has no side effect" to "unused variable".

Answer (score 2):

It is not a violation of the C Standard to discard the result of an expression.  Neither of the two expression statements in the question violates any rule or constraint.

Whether a compiler chooses to emit helpful warnings about various things is a quality-of-implementation issue, not governed by the Standard.

Calling a function but then not using its return value usually isn't a problem, because many (though certainly not all) functions do something other than just compute and return a value.  (The formal term for this is that many functions have *side effects*.)

The expression

```
(5>3) && (7>6);
```

is, on the other hand, perfectly useless.  It's clear that it doesn't do anything (it has no side effects), so the compiler is well advised to warn against it.

If a compiler writer decided to also helpfully warn about function return values that were ignored, there would be an immediate problem: virtually every C program contains multiple calls to `printf`, for which the return value is not checked.  So there would be so many false positives that the warning would be useless.

Comment: To avoid compiler warnings, cast the expression to `void`:

    `(void)( (5>3) && (7>6) );`

This is pointless in normal code, but might be useful in macro definitions.